# How to check if a response has string or integer value in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I tried using a regex for numbers only but it didn't work.

Blow snapshot shows my configuration. i tried various combinations like contains, matches etc. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to check a [Response Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) which is a **number**, i.e. `200` for success, `500` for server error, `400` for client error, etc.

It comes **without quotation marks** so you need to at least remove them from your regular expression

```
^[0-9]*$
```

Enhancement #1: response code is always a single line so you can convert it to

```
[0-9]*
```

Enhancement #2: response code always contains 3 digits so you can convert it to

```
[0-9]{3}
```

Enhancement #3: you can match any digit with `\d` shorthand so regular expression becomes

```
\d{3}
```

References:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet
- [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)